# VueJS : Adding to existing HTML and handling imports

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, axios, vue-component

So I built a Single Page Application in `VueJS` which works nicely but the *SEO* sucks as expected, so I decided to make a normal HTML site with some pages having `VueJS` code (Remote hosting so no node else I would go SSR).

I followed [this guide](https://medium.com/@disjfa/using-vue-js-in-existing-websites-the-easy-way-d46cd1f0c945) which works fin

I have a `search.js` which contains my `VueJS` instance and methods etc

```
Vue.component('todo-component', {
    template: '#todo-component',
    data: function () {
        return {
            items: [
                {
                    id: 'item-1',
                    title: 'Checkout vue',
                    completed: false
                }, {
                    id: 'item-2',
                    title: 'Use this stuff!!',
                    completed: false
                }
            ],
            newItem: ''

        };
    },
    methods: {
        addItem: function () {
            if (this.newItem) {
                var item = {
                    id: Math.random(0, 10000),
                    title: this.newItem,
                    completed: false
                };

                this.items.push(item);
                this.newItem = '';
            }
        }
    }
});

var app = new Vue({
    el: '#vue-app'
});
```

However, I need to import stuff like axios and other components

if I add an import statement to the script above, it comes up with

```
import axios from "axios";
```

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Where should my imports go?

Comment: DO you use any transpiler for your javascript? `import` is only natively supported by Google Chrome

Comment: I am not sure what transpiler are, I need this to work in all browsers

Comment: `import` cannot usually be used in embedded scripts; it's a feature that the transpiler (webpack or Vue CLI) handles by replacing the import with the code from the other module itself, but since you don't have a transpiler for directly embedding Vue in a page, you can't use it.

Details here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are directly writing code running in the browser, you can simply include the `axios` cdn in your html code before `search.js` is loaded:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
```

As for components import, you can read more about [component registration here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html). Generally if your components are registered globally via `Vue.component('my-component', {})` syntax, you should be able to directly use it within your code.

Comment: Excellent example mate, I don't suppose you know how to get lodash _.debounce to work with it to as it does not know what _ is (worked in my SPA)

Answer (score 2):

You're missing `axios` library so add it as follow :

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
```

i'm also providing you of how  to use it when you work with browser  :

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    dataReceived: '',
  },
  methods: {
    getData() {
      axios.get('https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=BTC&tsyms=USD')
        .then((response) => {
          this.dataReceived = response.data;
          console.log(this.dataReceived);
          return this.dataReceived;
        })
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="app">
    <button @click="getData" type="button">getData</button>
    <p>dataReceived: {{ dataReceived }}</p>
  </div>
</body>
```